# Future-Perfect?

Tags: verbs, grammar-identification, translation-explanation

In North & Hillard, Ex 215, the following sentence:

> There can be little doubt that the guides, whether through treachery or ignorance, were mainly responsible for the disaster.

is translated by the answer book as:

> parum quidem dubitari potest quin huius cladis, seu proditione seu inscientia, auctores in primis **fuerint** duces.

**Why deploy the future-perfect, *fuerint* ("they-will-have-been the creators of the disaster")?**

The English requires "were....responsible"; for me, there is a credible case for:

- *sunt* ("they are the creators"), even though the disaster has already happened;
- *erant*, giving the English: "they were"; and, presumably, continue to be responsible;
- yet again: *fuerunt* ("they were"): a completed process, in the past, now finished.

Any thoughts on why *fuerint* is used?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Looks like our edits collided: I rolled back and added the tags

Comment: @brianpck Thanks! Dealing with and even detecting edit collisions on the phone is confusing.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually perfect subjunctive following *quin*, which is permissible since it's a doubting clause. The two forms do look alike, but the *quin* is your giveaway. See [A&G 558](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-558.html) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you C.M. Weimer; thought of perf. subj., but, without ut/ne present dismissed this.

Comment: @tony The perfect subjunctive (conjunctive) does not require any particular conjunctions, so even adding *quin* and *quominus* to your list is not really sufficient.